# Parse through JSON in c# and xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a json string that I receive in c# that looks like this

```
{
"status": "error",
"data": {
    "first_name": ["The first name field is required."],
    "last_name": ["The last name field is required."],
    "email": ["The email field is required."],
    "password": ["The password field is required."]
    }
}
```

My code looks like this when calling the JSON string.  I am trying to parse the data to pull the values out of the Status and the Data.  However I am receiving errors whenever I get beyond making the request and to the actual parsing of the object.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Json_StatusResponse>(content);
var test = resp.first_name;
```

and my model looks like this:

```
public class Json_StatusResponse
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    //public string[][] data { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> data { get; set; }

    public class Data
    {
        public List<string> first_name { get; set; }
        public List<string> last_name { get; set; }
        public List<string> email { get; set; }
        public List<string> password { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }

}
```

For some reason I get

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.String[][]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'data.first_name', line 1, position 39.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> data { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Json_StatusResponse` does not match the JSON provided. you should probably be deserializing to the `RootObject` instead

I would recommend something like this:

```
public partial class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}

public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string[] FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string[] LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string[] Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string[] Password { get; set; }
}
```

and moving those nested classes out of `Json_StatusResponse`
The fields that you are using for your `Json_StatusResponse` are also not required (and from what I can tell, dont do anything)

you also need to be deserializing the `RootObject`, not `Json_StatusResponse` like so:

```
var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
var test = resp.Data.first_name[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON formatting is wrong "[]" incidate that something is an array. There your values are just single.

Modify your JSON to:

```
{
"status": "error",
"data": {
    "first_name": "The first name field is required.",
    "last_name": "The last name field is required.",
    "email": "The email field is required.",
    "password": "The password field is required."
    }
}
```

Also I recommend using JSON formatter website to validate your JSON:

[JSON Validator](https://jsonformatter.org/)